# facebook-chat-api doesn't run on react-native

Tags: android, facebook, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to work with this api with react-native, but after import - `var login = require("facebook-chat-api");` (i tried `import { login } from 'react-chat-api'` too but same) i am getting an error

[image]

[image]

I tried to fix error by disable debug mode, but there is other error message
[image]

Any tips if i can do something? Or this api just doesn't run on react-native? :/

Comment: what do you want to achieve? there is no chat api anymore. also, you are trying to access some path on your windows computer, that does not exist on android, of course...

Comment: oh, that npm module uses the user credentials...never ask users for those, see the disclaimer about banned accounts in the module description. also, i assume the module only works on node.js.